# How to change connection string in DataSet.xsd?

Tags: c#, connection-string, database-connection

I have build my project in C#, I add `DataSet.xsd`, and connect him to

Oracle DataBase in my computer - work Excellent !!!!

When I installed on the customer computer (that connect to his Oracle DataBase) -

it crushed.

I need to change the connection string on the `DataSet.xsd` file - but how to do it ?

Is there any xml file ? Or configuration file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When generating a DataSet with the Wizard you are asked to Create-and-Store a ConnectionString. Take a look in your App.Config

Comment: What if I need to encrypt the connection string? I have a similar problem, except that I want to use the encrypted connection created with the `aspnet_regiis` method and already stored on the app.config file. My Dataset.xsd still uses the ConnectionString stored on the Settings.settings file, automatically added with the Wizard.

Comment: Don't ask follow-ups in comments. Look for it and when you can't find it post a regular question.

Comment: Yes, you're right! And since I haven't found an answer I asked my own question. :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734610/how-to-use-encrypted-connection-string-on-app-config-with-dataset-xsd-generated Please take a look if you want!

Answer (score 20):

You can also open the Dataset and select the TableAdapter that you want to update, right click and go to properties.

here you will see a "connection" property that you can easily change to settings in your web.config file or enter new connection details.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012. I want to change the connection string to my remote web server. But I don't have direct access to the web server. The wizard does not allow my to add the adaptor. How can I change the connection string manually?

Answer (score 7):

I had similar situation... I'd already created lots of datasets, and they each recorded their own connection string in the code behind. A also manually interacted with database via connectionstring I'd placed in App.config file.
So to update all this when deploying to as-yet-unknown server would be pain; yet manually changing all those connectionstrings also put me off.
In the end I added a 'test' tableAdapter to the .xsd design page... and created a New connection string - this time specifying it be placed in App.config file. Then by magic... all the tableAdapters now used this one connectionstring - just delete the test object & voila!

Answer (score 5):

You can using like my code:
Note that DataSet can change connection string by app.config but you can change connection string by TableAdapter like below:

```
NCKHSV_TTD54TableAdapters.adtReportGiangVienTableAdapter tableAdapter = new 
NCKHSV_TTD54TableAdapters.adtReportGiangVienTableAdapter();//Create a TableAdapter to using.
 tableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = strConn;//change ConnectionString to strConn
 tableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
 tableAdapter.Fill(dataset.adtReportGiangVien);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just request server credentials in your application startup once or use a settings window and use this method:

get the connection string from SqlConnection object or form the connection string from individual data and do it like this:

```
[ApplicationNamespace].Properties.Settings.Default["ConnectionString"] = newconstr;
```

The application settings that are Application and not user scope can be set too.
But only programatically, by code. It works fine for me. Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Is this solution applicable on my .NET 4 Windows Form application if I want to use an encrypted connection string stored on the app.config file?

Comment: Simple and fast solution when you need to change the connection to the database on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

For WinForm its very simple. please refer below picture 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your Dataset is created, select the icon below of the columns that you selected to show. It ends with TableAdapter, go to properties. it shows the current connection string, just change it.

[image: Like this image]

Answer (score 1):

I was searching about way to change the `connectionsString` globally, and finally I find a way to do that.
Open dataset.xsd using notepad program and then replace the old connectionstring with the new one

```
<DbSource ConnectionRef="con_string_ar (Web.config)" DbObjectName="con_string_ar.dbo.albums" DbObjectType="Table"..>
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is stored sometimes in application settings (non-web projects: win forms, libraries...). Right click your project > Properties > Settings. You can then change connection string.

For best results, you can first open file `app.config` (for non-web projects) and modify your connection string. After that, open project settings to "let visual studio discover changes to connection string and update it automatically".